# Does using DuckDuckGo on Chrome or Chromium browsers eliminate the privacy advantage?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, chromium, search-engines

The search engine [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/privacy.html) purports to be much more private than other search engines such as Google.  However, I use the Google Chromium browser which, I believe is collecting data on my web usage.

So, is using a "private" search engine like DuckDuckGo with Chrome or Chromium effective in limiting the dissemination of my personal search data?

Comment: Technically if you connect to DuckDuckGo with https no data can be read between you and the DuckDuckGo search engine. While Google Chrome does take statistics I very much doubt they would be tracking individual site query’s this sounds like it would be a violation of privacy. If your really that paranoid start using Tor. or switch to another browser

Answer (score 3):

Chromium does't track any of the metrics or usage data that Chrome does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you support this with some more information?  As it is, it is just an assertion and it is difficult to assess its validity.

Comment: Yeah, sure. First off, using Chrome's omnibar with Google as the default search engine, _with auto complete on_ will allow Google to see all text input to said omnibar. This occurs weather you use Chrome or Chromium. Chromium is not branded by Google and is open source, I don't even think you have the option to share usage metrics on it, and it can be disabled from the settings in Chrome. Those are the only privacy concerns I've heard of that are Chrome related. Let me know if you have any other questions.